# Difficulty getting Caret GLM with Repeated CV to execute

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation

I have been doing 10X10-fold cv logistic models for a long time using homebrew code, but recently have figured that it might be nice to let caret handle the messy stuff for me.

Unfortunately, I seem to be missing some of the nuances that caret needs to be able to function.

Specifically, I keep getting this error:

```
>Error in { : task 1 failed - "argument is not interpretable as logical"
```

Please see if you can pick up what I am doing wrong...

Thanks in advance!

Data set is located [here](https://github.com/derekrucker/demodata/blob/master/Sample%20Data.csv).

```
dataset <- read.csv("Sample Data.csv")

library(caret)

my_control <- trainControl(
  method="repeatedcv",
  number=10,
  repeats = 10,
  savePredictions="final",
  classProbs=TRUE
)
```

This next block of code was put in there to make caret happy. My original dependent variable was a binary that I had turned into a factor, but caret had issues with the factor levels being "0" and "1". Not sure why.

```
dataset$Temp <- "Yes"
dataset$Temp[which(dataset$Dep.Var=="0")] <- "No"
dataset$Temp <- as.factor(dataset$Temp)
```

Now I (try) to get caret to run the 10X10-fold glm model for me...

```
testmodel <- train(Temp ~ Param.A + Param.G + Param.J + Param.O, data = dataset,
             method = "glm",
             trControl = my_control,
             metric = "Kappa")

testmodel


> Error in { : task 1 failed - "argument is not interpretable as logical"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Though you already found a fix by updating R and caret, I'd like to point out there is (was) a bug in your code which caused the error, and which I can reproduce here with an older version of R and caret:*

The `savePredictions` of `trainControl` is meant to be set to either `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of `'final'`. Seems you simply mixed it with the `returnResamp` parameter, which would take exactly this parameter.

BTW: R and caret have restrictions on level names of factors, which is why caret complained when you handed `0` and `1` level names for the dependent variable to it. Using a simple `dataset$Dep.Var <- factor(paste0('class', dataset$Dep.Var))` should do the trick in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that! I also like the factor naming trick. Strangely, I have used "0" and "1" in glm (without caret) as the factor names, and it had no issues. But I have no problems renaming the levels to make R and caret happy. :-)

Comment: Yw! AFAIK some models just don't complain about naming, but with caret this is something more consistent. Note that using `data.frame(check.names=T, ...)` will be useful too in such cases :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I am posting this as an answer. I ran your exact code, and it worked fine for me, twice. I did get this warning:

```
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

As per the author, this error had something to do with the savePredictions parameter. Have a look at this issue: 
https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/304

Comment: Thanks for running the code. I am still getting the original error, though. I know what the glm.fit warning is all about. But I can't even get it to create the darn model. Maybe I'll update to a more current version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sumedh, I figured that the problem might not be with my code, and I updated all my packages.

Surprise! Now it works. So I wasn't crazy after all.

Sorry all for the fire drill.